# Javascript - Formatting Date string to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: javascript

I need to express a Date as a String with the exact format format:

```
 2015-01-20
```

I see there is an date.toIsoFormatString() but not sure where or how to provide the format shown above.

```
 Here is my code:

 var future = new Date();
 future.setDate(future.getDate() + 30);
 console.log(future);
```

Now I want future.toString() or future.toIsoFormatString() to display the date in just the YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: And any of [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript) or the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) couldn't solve your problem?

Comment: No Teemu. No   console.log(future.toString('yyyy-MM-dd')); taken directly from this answer yields:  Sun Mar 01 2015 15:01:59 GMT-0800 (PST), but if you can think of an answer please post it.

Comment: No? Just keep digging ... ; )

Comment: www.stackoverflow.com --> www.justkeepdigging.com ? :)

Comment: Guess I've had too much Vodka ...

Comment: Well, I could have boiled it down to four letters (RTFM), I thought the dig stuff would be nicer to read. Btw. please be careful with the Vodka ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [momentJs](http://momentjs.com/) library for formated date.

Example without momentJs :

```
 myDate = new Date();
 myDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (myDate.getMonth()+1) + "-" + myDate.getDate() // 2015-1-31
```

Example with momentJs :

```
moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD") // 2015-01-31
```

MomentJs have many others useful function

Answer (score 6):

IE>8 and all other updated browsers can do this natively-

```
new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);
```

Comment: *toISOString* uses UTC, whereas the OP appears to want the local date. This will produce the wrong local date for the period of the timezone offset adjacent to midnight.